# Is there a way to Mask the Inputbox object easily

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

In my WinForms project, I have 2 Inputboxes pop up asking the user for a username and a password and I would like to mask the text entry on the password inputbox.

Currently the code simply looks like:

```
_Passwd = InputBox("Please Enter the Corresponding Password" & vbCrLf & _
                   "Leave blank to abort program", "New Credentials Needed", "")
```

I was wondering if there was either a way to mask the text on the inputbox or if there was another pre-defined object in .Net I could use without creating my own userform with a masked textbox? (I know it's easy, just seems like more hassle than is needed if Microsoft already has it pre-created)

Comment: Bite the bullet and make your own form.  The InputBox always looks unprofessional (my opinion).

Comment: A `Textbox` control can be used as a password input by setting the `PasswordChar` property to anything other than an empty string.  I think 2GDev answer is a good option since you have access to the textbox functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built-in for this -- you have to create your own.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but from description may help you :

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1e5295a5-d7bd-4789-bced-361c608a3a7e

Comment: Thanks, @2GDev - A good thing to know, but still something I'd have to create myself.